# How to do fix the position of the publication header in the Ghost casper theme?

Tags: css, ghost

The casper theme is great.  But I'd like to make a few tweaks.

HTML layout and css trickery is not something I do.  So here we go...

I'd like to fix the position of the site header so that scrolling the articles glides neatly over top.

Simply changing the css for position:fixed on the `site-header` class almost works, in that it stays put.  But doing that changes the layout in a rather ugly way.  i.e. It moves the site header left and it all the posts on the main page shift up over the top of the title so when you first load the page you can't see it.  This is unexpected for someone who's not terribly savvy beyond very basic css.

Answer (score 1):

I just set this up myself. Two small tweaks are needed. On `site-header`, set a `z-index` (I picked 1000) and set `width: 100%`. Then, add an appropriate amount of `padding-top` to `site-main`. The best way to add this padding would be JS (dynamically check the outer-height of `site-header`) but if you are reasonably sure your header won't shift sizes, go ahead and hard-code it.

Answer (score 0):

For v4 of casper, add this to the `.gh-head` class. You can either modify the theme files or do code injection. The `sticky` property is supported for 95+% of users. Check [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=sticky) for a comprehensive list. The high `z-index` takes care of content not going over your header when scrolling.

```css
.gh-head {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Older Safari browsers */
    position: sticky; /* Most other modern browsers including Safari */
    top: 0;
    z-index: 4000;
}
```